# About the von Neumann entropy after the partial trace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

In the quantum information field, it is widely known that the von Neumann entropy of a state $\rho$ is 0 if and only if $\rho$ is a pure state. If we restrict the state as a pure entangled state, is the von Neumann entropy of the partial-traced state not 0? For example, when $\left | \psi\right >=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (\left | 00\right >+\left | 11\right >)\in \mathbb{H}_A\otimes \mathbb{H}_B$, the partial-traced state is $\rho _A=\rho _B = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{I}$ so that the von Neumann entropy is not 0. I wonder if this property generally holds.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the state
$$
|\phi^+\rangle_{AB} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)
$$

This is a maximally entangled Bell state that lives in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H_A} \otimes \mathcal{H_B}$. It is entangled, which can be seen by considering the entanglement entropy of one of its subsystems. The density matrix for subsystem A can be obtained by tracing over the degrees of freedom that are not local to A, i.e. those in B.
\begin{align}
\rho_A &= \text{Tr}_B(\rho_{AB})\\
       &= \frac{1}{2}\langle0|_B(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)(\langle11|+\langle00|)|0\rangle_B + \frac{1}{2}\langle1|_B(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)(\langle11|+\langle00|)|1\rangle_B \\
      &= \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle_A\langle0|_A) + \frac{1}{2}(|1\rangle_A\langle1|_A)\\
      &= \frac{1}{2} I_{2x2}
\end{align}

So here the von Neumann entropy is 
$$
S(A)=-\text{Tr}\rho \log{\rho} = \log{2}
$$
i.e. the state is entangled. However, the von Neumann entropy for the original state considered as a member of $\mathcal{H_A} \otimes \mathcal{H_B}$ is 0, as required for a pure state. So the von Neumann entropy for the whole state is 0, but the subsystems are entangled (von Neumann entropy strictly positive).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I made a mistake. I changed my question so could you teach me your answer again?